# What happens to Rails session after :expire_after time is up?

Tags: session, ruby-on-rails-4

Does the session become nil? Does the change take effect only on the next request?

I think I just asked three questions now...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try to explore by using the similar settings:

```
AppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_session_key', expire_after: 20.seconds
```

Then open up dev tools in your browser and go to `cookies` and select `localhost` cookies to see what happens.

I found out that:

1. Session cookie gets deleted after the expiration time
2. Expiration time for a cookie gets updated automatically (re-set) upon any request (even background ajax request counts)
3. The effect by default will take place upon the next request (refreshing the page for example) and if you use typical authentication (has_secure_password_ for example) user should be logged out

I found [the last comment](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base) on the `ActionController::Base` documentation page really helpful on this topic